# How can you disable zooming in Internet Explorer and Firefox?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer

The zooming features in both Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox really bother me. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (TrackPad Click) to open new tabs and often my finger will graze the track pad which activates the zoom feature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + [mouse wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel) basically). Then normally the tab, which was just opened, will be 1000% or 10%.

How can I disable this feature, I will never need it?

Comment: It sort of worries me that my first thought was: "Use autohotkey to disable control and mousewheel if firefox is active", as the below about:config hacks are much better for it.

Comment: I actually have that set to alt-tab instead. Nice actually...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Firefox**

Enter **about:config** in the address bar. Now, look for **zoom.maxPercent** and **zoom.minPercent** and fix their values to **100**.

---

**Internet Explorer**

For Internet Explorer, I think this is what you meant:

Go to menu Tools >> Internet Options >> Advanced and check that box.

[image]

Comment: For Firefox, a restart of the application is required before zoom.maxPercent and zoom.minPercent takes effect (at least for some versions of Firefox). Otherwise it can become very confusing changing the values.

Answer (score 4):

In Firefox, if you still want the option of zooming with `ctrl--` and `ctrl-=`, you can go to about:config and set `mousewheel.withcontrolkey.action` to 0. This makes it so scrolling with the control key down does the same as scrolling without the control key.

I couldn't figure out how to disable the ctrl-scroll binding entirely.

Comment: nowadays this is `mousewheel.with_control.action`