# Lock/disable the zoom on Chrome Browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, web, zoom

Is there a way to disable/lock the mouse/touchpad zoom in the Chrome browser? I find myself accidentally triggering ctrl-wheel or touchpad-two-finger far more often than do intentionally.

As an afterwards bandaid fix, Ctrl-0 will quickly restore zoom to 100%.

Comment: This is a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253697). Please star it.

Comment: --disable-pinch works for pinch-zooms, but does not fix ctrl-wheel resizing.   (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999829/disable-chrome-pinch-zoom-for-use-in-kiosk)

Answer (score 10):

For a quick and dirty solution I found @ http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/-rtDLZmN9bk

Followed rd2020's comment for AutoHotkey (as I am already running it for other things)

Downloaded AutoHotKey software 
In the AutoHotkey.ahk file, added these to do nothing for Cntrl+MouseWheelScrolling

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
{
    ^WheelDown::return 
    ^WheelUp::return
    #MaxHotkeysPerInterval 1000
}
```

Comment: This solution still works in 2017.

Comment: Note, use administrator authority to run this AHK ,or it would not take effect .

Answer (score 2):

There is an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-mousewheel-zoom/ckhlfagjncfmdieecfekjbpnnaekhlhd) that can prevent it.

Just make sure to

> ## NoMouseWheelZoom
>
> Installation Instructions
>       1. Install the extension
>       2. Go to extension settings. Make sure that "allow access to file url's" is checked
>       3. Refresh Your tabs

Comment: NoMouseWheelZoom currently (end 2016) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
<meta content='True' name='HandheldFriendly' />
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
```

not work for you?

Comment: how/where would you put that? As a userscript or through something else?

Comment: That does work, but it's for the wrong problem ;) After a way to lock browser zoom on all sites

Comment: Any way to make this work on any browser (desktop or mobile)?

Comment: The content of viewport should be comma delimited.

Answer (score -1):

However this is not possible yet on chrome but you can use an extension called [zoom lock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/obekapoaicdbgecpanmhkajdngnoackj).

For windows there is a solution on [Google product forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/-rtDLZmN9bk) `open the - controlpanel hardware settings mouse device settings`, and then search for the setting were you can disabe the pinch zoom.

Also see this [discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/X0wTNQpfl2k).

Comment: Thanks for googling it, but Zoom Lock does NOT lock the zoom to a set level, it allows you to predetermine zoom levels for your favourite sites. Nor does disabling the shortcut with Shortcut Manager. Disabling pinchzoom for the whole system is a "workaround", not a solution, and eliminates a core functionality that is very useful in many other scenarios.

Comment: @WulfSolter Here is an alternative extension "Zoom Block", which actually does prevent zoom modifications (until re-enabled for a specific tab): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-block/jmomepcgehgfoimapeoinphcloinjfpb