# Completely disable zooming in Google Chrome on Mac

Tags: mac, google-chrome

A keyboard shortcut (Control+Option+scroll up / down) I use constantly trigger accidental page zoom in Google chrome. I would like a way to disable this behavior or even completely disable zooming in google chrome if that's what it takes. Any ideas?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/243127/disable-ctrlmouse-wheel-zooming-in-chrome any help?

Comment: I saw that question. It didn't seem to be for Macintosh though, that's why I asked this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't per a search.  Please also note this question may be closed as it may be a duplicate to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/428712/lock-disable-the-zoom-on-chrome-browser) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/243127/disable-ctrlmouse-wheel-zooming-in-chrome)

Answer from official Google board [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/X0wTNQpfl2k).

> You can't turn off the zoom feature on Chrome

Comment: I have seen both questions. However neither of which targeted the Mac platform. That's why I asked a new question, thinking perhaps the answer is different for each platform.

Comment: Android is a mobile OS with completely different UI. I think you meant windows / linux. Chrome has a common codebase in C++ for all platforms but has platform specific bindings especially when it comes to user interface (that's why chrome on mac looks native, as is chrome on windows). And to achieve this may not even require chrome's cooperation depending on which OS you are running (e.g. system override the shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

The 'Zoom Block' chrome extension should work on any platform (works for me on ubuntu):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-block/jmomepcgehgfoimapeoinphcloinjfpb?hl=en