# Mouse wheel scroll causes zoom in/out in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mouse-wheel

When scrolling using the mouse wheel scroll in Google Chrome, there is about 25% chance it would **zoom** in/out as if I have pressed the Ctrl key.

Disabling my mouse gesture extension reduces the chance to only about 2%.

I have tried **various** extensions and noticed some mouse gesture extensions seem to make it a bit worse than the others. I am guessing the problem is with Chrome or its extensions.

I believe it is **not** my hardware or software.

1. It happens in Chrome on **both** my Windows 7 desktop computers at work and at home
2. It never happens in Firefox on either computer (I use both browsers)
3. I tried turning on "Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key" so I know if the Ctrl is pressed accidentally - it never was.
4. I don't have AutoHotKey or anything similar installed on Windows.

Is this a Google Chrome bug? Is there a workaround?

**UPDATE:**
I installed AutoHotKey to nullify Ctrl+scroll.
Ctrl+scroll now does nothing, but scrolling normally still often zooms.

Comment: likely duplicate (or, at least, similar solutions) http://superuser.com/questions/243127/disable-ctrlmouse-wheel-zooming-in-chrome

Comment: Posting this as a comment as it's not a solution for everyone: I was experiencing the same issue in Chrome while using my Logitech mouse (M705). The issue for me was that the default assignment of the scroll wheel when [accidentally or intentionally] clicked is to zoom. The solution was to disable this assignment in Logitech Control Center which is the configuration software that can be downloaded from their site.

Comment: The problem itself is not Windows specific. I am looking for platform independent solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dont know where from this problem comes. but we can have an alternative solution to that. Depending on the drivers for your mouse, you could set ctrl-scroll as a "shortcut" to actually do nothing - essentially capturing the combination and throwing it away. Some drivers will even let you specify this for only within a certain application, at which point you'd specify chrome.

**OR**

Another trick would be:

solution using AutoHotKey posted on google groups:

```
Using Logitech Performance Mouse MX...

Downloaded AutoHotKey software

In the AutoHotkey.ahk file, added these to do nothing for Cntrl+MouseWheelScrolling

^WheelDown::return

^WheelUp::return
```

http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/-rtDLZmN9bk/5pJYksjrvQUJ

**Also** 
if this doesn't work,
please provide some more information about your hardware please..

**UPDATE - The solution**

It looks like the zooming issue is related to mouse scrolling freeware. I took a look at a tool I run called "WizMouse." The purpose of these tools is to allow scrolling windows without focusing on them. Settings can be changed in these to fix the problem.

Resolutions:

- KatMouse (per nsx82): Add class: Chrome_WidgetWin_1, and under the settings tick option: "Window has scrolling wheel support?" (try checked first)
- WizMouse (per JoPa Mi): Uncheck "Enable mouse wheel for applications without mouse wheel support"

Comment: It doesn't work, interesting... Now I can't zoom anymore by using Ctrl+scroll, but scrolling normally (without pressing Ctrl) still often zooms!  My home and office hardware are quite different, I doubt it is the hardware. But what do you need to know?

Comment: It looks like the zooming issue is related to mouse scrolling freeware.  I took a look at a tool I run called "WizMouse." The purpose of these tools is to allow scrolling windows without focusing on them. Settings can be changed in these to fix the problem.

Resolutions:

KatMouse (per nsx82): Add class: Chrome_WidgetWin_1, and under the settings tick option: "Window  has scrolling wheel support?" (try checked first)

WizMouse (per JoPa Mi): Uncheck "Enable mouse wheel for applications without mouse wheel support"

http://ehiti.de/katmouse/

Comment: Wow how could you even think of that. I'm in the office, did what you said to my KatMouse and so far the scroll has been perfect! But I don't even have KatMouse at home... but may be a similar software, I'll check it at home.

Comment: I think it solved the problem! I'm adding your comment that solved the problem into your answer, and accepting that. Thank you Rachit!

Comment: I use KatMouse and your note about adding the class=`Chrome_WidgetWin_1` fixed the problem for me. (I had to uncheck the box for "window has wheel scrolling support"). Note: I also had to click *Apply* in the KatMouse settings to see the effect (at first I *thought* my change didn't work. Luckily I noticed that before trying some more complicated solution ;)

Comment: Chrome extension to smooth wheel scrolling was causing same issue with Zooming on Windy.com!

Answer (score 10):

I've been annoyed by this for a long time, but when I searched most recently, I found a Chrome Extension that disables this Ctrl-scroll zoom behavior called [No MouseWheel Zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-mousewheel-zoom/ckhlfagjncfmdieecfekjbpnnaekhlhd).

It worked fairly well, but didn't do exactly what I wanted (I wanted scrolling to continue as usual, even if I had pressed Ctrl. The extension just stopped scrolling and zooming altogether when Ctrl was pressed). So, I decided to make my own extension, which I just published yesterday. It converts Ctrl-scroll back into normal scrolling, and it's called [ZoomToScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoomtoscroll/iaehfjjafflijdgfoglcpgjpgabghcel).

Check these two extensions out and see if either one of them does what you want.

Comment: I just tried it and can also confirm it works. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an AutoHotKey script that will remove the Ctrl+Wheel gesture from just Chrome and leave it for other appliations:

```
;Disable mouse wheel zooming in Chrome 
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 
    ^WheelDown::return 
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 
    ^WheelUp::return
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround: this extension disables page zooming in general, unless/until enabled for specific tabs: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-block/jmomepcgehgfoimapeoinphcloinjfpb