# How can I disable control mouse wheel on windows?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Couldn't find any solution on the Web or SU. Is it possible to disable `control-mouse-wheel-zoom` functionality for `Chrome` on `Windows 7`?

Comment: Does this other superuser article help?

http://superuser.com/questions/243127/disable-ctrlmouse-wheel-zooming-in-chrome

Comment: I don't use Logitech Performance Mouse MX.

Comment: @CharlieRB, not phrased as a duplicate so may not be though detail is lacking in the question. I'd recommend that the OP updates the question with a little more detail. I don't think this is possible without using some form of advanced mouse driver such as the Microsoft or Logitech ones.